# is it safe to delete magento 2 table:fl32_csp_report?

Tags: magento2.3, database, table

I have the following table, named fl32_csp_report, size: 2.5GB.  it's very huge table, and it affected the visiting speed when customers comes to my website. My store has been just updated from Magento 1 to Magento 2 one year before.  I couldn't find any information in google about how to truncate this table.  If I truncate it, will any serious problem be caused ? I will appreciate if anyone could supply me any information about it.

P.S: version: 2.3.5-p1   database: mysql 5.3.1

Comment: There is no core table `fl32_csp_report` in magento. This table must have been created from one of your custom module

Comment: thanks  
Shoaib Munir,maybe it is an extension called: mageplaza

Comment: It's this extension: https://github.com/flancer32/mage2_ext_csp

Answer (score 0):

There is no core table fl32_csp_report in magento. This table must have been created from **Magento 2 Advanced Reports Extension - Mageplaza**

Based on module requirement you can perform needed action.

Comment: If that's the case, Mageplaza copied the extension from here: https://github.com/flancer32/mage2_ext_csp

Comment: @FabianSchmengler may be.. not sure